# paypal sandbox completed the payment successfully, but my script didn't receive the ipn post call

Tags: php, paypal

I am developing with paypal sandbox, all the payment flow can go successfully without any error. I set up 'notify_url' in my form and this url can be successfully tested by  Instant Payment Notification (IPN) Simulator.

Paypal sandbox told me the payment completed successfully but my ipn handler could not receive any requests.

by the way I am using this ipn library: https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN

Comment: i would check the access log to see if papal hit another page.

Comment: @Dagon The scripts was working before

Comment: sorry to many possibilities, i don't know what to suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm your IPN History is / keeps blank?

For me, it seems like Paypal is having Problems with their Sandbox IPN again.
They had similar problems till about 2 weeks ago:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/instant-payment-notifications-ipn-payment-data-transfer-pdt/ipn-failing-hasn-t-been-changed

I can confirm it was working again as the thread at x.com tells but for about 2 or 3 days (I guess) I do not get any IPN anymore although the payment itself is processed fine.

There is already a new thread at x.com that may cover our problem, but unfortunately there are no answers so far: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/instant-payment-notifications-ipn-payment-data-transfer-pdt/ipn-message-not-sent-url-mentioned-under-notify-_url-sandbox

Btw: I'm pretty sure this is not related to PHP or the library you use since I have the same problems using Ruby and the guy asking at x.com is using Java.